# Assign values from another table based on time range

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have T1 :

```
id         date        attribute
1        2017-04-20        t
1        2017-04-19        t
1        2017-04-18        t
2        2017-04-20        t
2        2017-04-19        f
```

And I also have T2 :

```
 id         date        date_end    attribute
  1        2017-04-19   2017-04-25      f
```

What I want is to get a new table, which would contain data from T1 but in case there is matching ids in both table, replace the attribute value in T1 with the attribute value in T2 for the date range defined in T2.

The result would look like this:

```
id         date        attribute
    1        2017-04-20        f
    1        2017-04-19        f
    1        2017-04-18        t
    2        2017-04-20        t
    2        2017-04-19        f
```

What I have come up with is the following:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.date,
CASE WHEN max(T2.id) IS NULL THEN T1.attribute ELSE T2.attribute END 
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 using (id)
```

Can't figure out how to change the attributes for the particular range. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.date,
       COALESCE(t2.attribute, t1.attribute) as attribute
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
     T2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id AND
        t1.date >= t2.date and t1.date <= t2.date_end;
```

Comment: Works amazing! So easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.date,
  CASE 
    WHEN a.date BETWEEN b.date AND b.date_end THEN b.attribute
    ELSE a.attribute
  END AS attribute
FROM T1 AS a
LEFT JOIN T2 AS b
ON a.id = b.id
```

You can play/test it with sample data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH T1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2017-04-20' AS date, 't' AS attribute UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2017-04-19', 't' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2017-04-18', 't' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-04-20', 't' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-04-19', 'f' 
),
T2 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2017-04-19' AS date, '2017-04-25' AS date_end, 'f' AS attribute
)
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.date,
  CASE 
    WHEN a.date BETWEEN b.date AND b.date_end THEN b.attribute
    ELSE a.attribute
  END AS attribute
FROM T1 AS a
LEFT JOIN T2 AS b
ON a.id = b.id
-- ORDER BY 1,2 DESC
```